# Unity NavMeshSurface Loading Incorrectly

Tags: unity-game-engine, dynamic, navmesh

I am having trouble with the NavMeshSurface build process at runtime. I followed Unity's tutorial for using the NavMeshSurface features...

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/making-it-dynamic?playlist=17105

...and integrated it with my project successfully. However, when the level builds the Navmesh, it builds it 90 degrees perpindicular to my level.

Visual of Navmesh being built at runtime at 90 degree perpendicular to level. NOTE: Heightmesh is being built just fine.
[image]

The tutorial didn't show any signs of this being a problem. Currently my level is being built on the XZ axis because Navmesh surfaces won't generate on the XY plane. I have tried rotating the level 90 degrees but then nothing is created. I also have taken a screenshot of my current NavMeshSettings if that will help.

Snapshot of current NavmeshSurface settings in case I have something set incorrectly.
[image]

I'm no stranger to coding, I just haven't worked with dynamic navmesh before. So if there is something else you need feel free to ask and I can post it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Generate the Navmesh so it is correct, then rotate your level to how you need it. Create the NavMeshSurface on its own gameobject as a child of your level, then attach your NavMesh data to the NavMeshSurface. You can rotate the child object to then match your level again.

Comment: Help me to solve this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117631/navmeshagent-player-not-parallel-to-slope-of-hill-when-moving-over-hill**